# How to retrieve the sum of a field based on a specific year (ex: 2018 minus 1 = 2017)?

Tags: tableau-api

I have 3 years, 2016, 2017 and 2018. I would like to retrieve a specific field sum value for example of the previous year 2017. I don't want to hard code it so that it takes current year (2018) minus 1 year and calculates the sum of that specific field which we will call OT.
Anyone knows how to proceed?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: I haven't got the faintest idea what this question is asking; can you clarify the question, preferably by showing some code?

Comment: But generally the way you proceed when you don't know how to get started is: find a simpler problem. Suppose you *did* hard-code the year; could you solve the problem then and find the sum? What does that code look like? If you don't know how to solve that problem, then again *find a simpler problem*. Can you hard code the year and, instead of finding a sum, find a *single value*?  What does *that* code look like?  And so on. Keep simplifying until you can write code.

Comment: I can get the previous year with `INT(Year)-1` but I don't know how to proceed afterwards. I would like to filter a specific field called OT, get the sum based on the previous year with the use of calcfield

Comment: Another technique that I like to use to get started is: suppose you had a magical method that did exactly what you want.  **What is the signature of that method**?  That is, what are the types of its inputs and its output? Once you have the signature then you can start working it from both ends; what intermediate results do you need to get in order to transform the inputs to the outputs? Then make methods for *those*, and so on.

Comment: Ok, I will investigate. I have added a picture for clarification

Comment: That picture clarifies nothing; provide *code*. This is a site for *questions about code*, so post the code you have written so far and ask a *specific* question about it *that has an answer*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is OT the field you want to sum? If so, let's assume the field for year is simply called YEAR. You want last year. So it would look something like this in the calculation you create. Let's assume you name the custom calculation CALC:

```
case [YEAR]
   when year(now()) - 1 
   then [OT]
   else null end
```

So the above is the forumula stored in CALC. It's a measure. Now you just use it the way you would any other measure. For sum, it would be sum([CALC]). That will be the total [OT] for the prior year.